# how to VISIBLE a button randomly

Tags: java, android, button

there are 5 buttons in layout that I had made them INVISIBLE before and also I had generated a random number between 1 to 5. I want to know how to relate those numbers with buttons ,for example if the random number was 1 then the first button should be made VISIBLE.
actually I want to avoid using if and switch statements like this

```
Button btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
.
.
.
Button btn_5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_5);
int a = new Random().nextInt(4)+1;

if(a==1){
btn_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}else....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put all buttons in to array, randomly get number from 0 to 4 and set visibility by randomly generated number as index. `buttonsArray.get(generatedNumber).setVisibility(VISIBLE);`

Here is full working code:

```
        Button btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        Button btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        Button btn_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
        Button btn_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_4);
        Button btn_5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_5);

        ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
        buttons.add(btn_1);
        buttons.add(btn_2);
        buttons.add(btn_3);
        buttons.add(btn_4);
        buttons.add(btn_5);

        int maximum = buttons.size() - 1;
        int minimum = 0;

        Random rn = new Random();
        int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
        int randomNumber = rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;

        Button randomButton = buttons.get(randomNumber);

        randomButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```